# Why does my -match call include an invalid item when getting network drives?

Tags: powershell, drive

When calling

```
Get-PsDrive | Select Name,Root
```

I can see the followng drives:

```
Name       Root                               
----       ----                               
Alias                                         
C          C:\                                
Cert       \                                  
Env                                           
Function                                      
G          \\company.com\EVP\Data\Gen...
HKCU       HKEY_CURRENT_USER                  
HKLM       HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE                 
Variable                                      
WSMan                                         
X          \\server\C$               
Z          \\server\C$
```

Great. Now I only want the network drives, ie drives where `Root` contains `\\` and `Provider` is `FileSystem`.

So I tried

```
Get-PSDrive | 
    where {$_.Provider -match "FileSystem" -and $_.Root -match "\\"} 
        | Select -ExpandProperty Name
```

But this includes the `C` drive for some reason. How is that possible?

I also tried changing to

```
$_.Root -match "\\\"
```

But I get

> parsing "\\" - Illegal \ at end of pattern.

and

```
$_.Root -match "\\\\"
```

returns nothing.

Comment: `-match` is for regular expressions so you either have to use `$_.Root -match "\\\\"` (or even better `$_.Root -match "^\\\\"`) or just go with `$_.Root -like '\\*'`

Comment: Can you try `Get-PSDrive |  where {$_.Provider -match "FileSystem" -and $_.DisplayRoot -match "\\\\"}  | Select -ExpandProperty Name`

Answer (score -1):

`-match` takes a regular expression (regex) on the right, and in regular expression language a backslash is an escape character, and the way to specify a backslash is to escape it with another one - i.e. `\\` translates to a single backslash, which matches drives like `C:\`.

Your options are:

```
$_ -match '\\\\'    # two escaped backslashes

$_ -match [regex]::Escape('\\')   # it returns \\\\ but maybe clearer to a reader what's happening

$_.StartsWith('\\')    # don't use a regex, use a .Net string method
```

Edit:

> As I mentioned in my question, when trying to -match with '\\', I get no return value.

Run `Get-PsDrive Z | Format-List -Property *` and see something like:

```
Used            : 89738715136
Free            : 29716107264
CurrentLocation :
Name            : Z
Provider        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem
Root            : Z:\
Description     :
MaximumSize     :
Credential      : System.Management.Automation.PSCredential
DisplayRoot     : \\localhost\c$
```

and it shows that the property `root` is really the drive letter, and the UNC path is called `DisplayRoot`. I don't know why, but it looks like the output formatting system is showing the DisplayRoot value and presenting it as the Root value. But that's just happening at the final presentation step, you can't use it in your script.

@Lieven Keersmaekers' suggestion of using `$_.DisplayRoot -match '\\\\'` is good.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, when trying to `-match` with `'\\\\'`, I get no return value. How can that be?

Comment: @Bassie, did you try my comment? If that works, I have a theory *(otherwise I have no idea :))*

Comment: Bassie I've edited my answer, @LievenKeersmaekers's answer seems good.